# What does $M$ mean in this context?

Tags: real-analysis

Was reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603291/how-to-show-some-function-is-constant#comment1270840_603291) which posed the following:

> Suppose $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $\left| \;f(x) - f(y) \; \right| \le M \;\left|\;x-y\;\right|^{\alpha} $ for some  $\alpha > 1$
> and all $x,y \in (a,b) $ , prove that $f$ is constant on $(a,b)$.

A basic question:  What does $M$ mean in this context?

The other answerers seemed to know very well what this meant, but that's probably because they've taken a course in real analysis, which I haven't.  I understand everything else above, though.

Comment: It's a generic constant. There should be an "and some $M \geqslant 0$" after the "for some $\alpha \leq 1$" or somewhere else. The assumptions are that there are some $M,\alpha$ such that $f$ satisfies $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert \leqslant M\cdot \lvert x-y\rvert^\alpha$ for all $x,y$. And, by the way, one needs $\alpha > 1$ for the conclusion that $f$ is constant. That has just been corrected, it was erroneously changed by a suggested edit.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer. Magdiragdag's answer says that $M$ is positive. You're saying it's non-negative. Does it matter? (Though I guess if it's zero it's easy to prove?)

Comment: Not really. In case $M = 0$, it is immediate that $f$ must be constant, regardless of $\alpha$. The interesting case is $M > 0$.

Comment: $M$ could even be negative and the statement would still be true :-)

Comment: @Magdiragdag In that case, vacuously. $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert \leqslant M\cdot \lvert x-y\rvert^\alpha$ can only hold for $M < 0$ if $\lvert x-y\rvert^\alpha = 0$.

Comment: I didn't say it was an exciting case :-)

Comment: @John : the question is poorly worded.  They probably should have added "for some $M > 0$" or for some $M \geq 0$"(if $M=0$, then $f$ is trivially constant.  $M<0$ is impossible except perhaps if you allow $a=b$, in which case $(a,b)$ is the "empty interval" $\varnothing$ and the condition on $f$ is true because any universal statement about the empty set is true.  I really doubt they meant that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's some arbitrary positive constant.

Comment: correction: NONNEGATIVE CONSTANT