# Prove that $h(x) = \int f(x)dx$ is continuous $\forall$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for given conditions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:R \rightarrow R$ is a real valued function $\forall$ $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y|^3$$

Prove that $h(x) = \int f(x)dx$ is continuous $\forall$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Now, my thought process here is I'll probably need to procced by using differentiability and differentiating the function, since I can see it having the form of differentiation by first principle when I just rearrange the equation a bit:
$$\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} \leq |x-y|^2$$

But I dont know how to proceed here? Also, what should be my thought process approaching this question here? I know that proving that a function is differentiable also proves that it is continuous, but how do I go about differentiating here after I get the above form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show that every $\alpha$-Hölder function, with $\alpha > 1$, is constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603291/how-to-show-that-every-alpha-h%c3%b6lder-function-with-alpha1-is-constant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take limit in your inequality as $y \to x$. You see that $f'(x)$ exists and equals $0$. Since this is true for all $x$, $f$ must be  a constant.