# Showing that if a function between metric spaces has Hölder exponent $\alpha > 1$, this function must be constant

Tags: metric-spaces, holder-spaces

Let us recall the definition of a *Hölder continuous function* in the most general setting:

> Let $(M,d)$ and $(M',d')$ be two metric spaces. A function $f : M \to
> M'$ is said to be **Hölder continuous with exponent
>   $\alpha$**, $0 < \alpha \leq 1$, if there exists a real constant $C$
>   s.t. $$d(f(x),f(y)) \leq C d(x,y)^\alpha$$ holds for all $x,y \in M$.

Now the question is why do we only consider $0 < \alpha \leq 1$. As I heard in todays lecture, this is because if $\alpha > 1$, then the only functions satisfying the above criterion are the constant ones. So naturally I wanted to prove this, but I got stuck. I mean, I think the best way of proving this is by contradiction: Hence assume that $f(x) \neq f(y)$ for some $x,y \in M$. Moreover, the above condition implies that $f$ is continuous.

My question (since I've searched for answers already, but only found the case where $M$ is an interval): How does one prove that if $\alpha > 1$, then $f$ must be constant? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Note: If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, then the Hölder condition implies that $f'$ is identically $0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/578487/169085

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is: this is wrong. You can look in [On Jordan Arcs and Lipschitz functions defined on them](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485889215) by Besicovitch and Schoenberg.

Regarding your question, the important parts are the theorem 1 and the beginning of page $116$ : there exists an arc $J \subset \mathbb{C}$ and an injective function $f : J \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x,y \in J$, $|f(x)-f(y)| \le |x-y|^{\frac{3}{2}}$.

$ $

Usually I prefer to look at their result the other way around : for $0 \le \varepsilon<\frac{1}{2}$, there exists $g : [0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ a continuous function such that for all $x,y \in [0,1]$, $|g(x)-g(y)| \ge |x-y|^{\varepsilon}$.

(You get to this by considering reciprocal functions : for $\varepsilon=\frac{2}{3}$, you just have to rescale $f$ as defined in the previous paragraph and take $g=f^{-1}$).

$ $

*Note that "arc" is to be understood simply as [the image of $[0,1]$ by a continuous injective function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{C}$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Jordan_Arc).*

Answer (score 4):

This is false. Consider $(M,d)=(M',d')=(\{a,b\},d)$ where $d(a,b) = 1$. Let $f: M \to M, f(a) = a, f(b) = b$, and $C = 1$. Then the Hölder condition is satisfied for any $\alpha > 0$ (I guess any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$).

What was probably meant in the lecture is that in the case that $(M',d) = \mathbb{R}$ and $(M,d) = \mathbb{R}^n$ (for some $n$), if a function satisfies a Hölder $\alpha$ condition with $\alpha > 1$, then it must be constant. Note the main reason this is true is the dilation structure of $\mathbb{R}$, which is not present in my counterexample above ($d(x,y)$ is never between $0$ and $1$, so raising it to the $\alpha > 1$ won't make it very small).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, what was meant in the lecture was the euclidean case. I thought that it might work also in the general case. Somehow I was misguided by the wikipedia article which I interpreted falsely.